# Java - Wait for stream to finish writing?

Tags: java, android, sockets, arrays, outputstream

I have a "server" running in java and I am sending files via byte array to a "client" (android system). The functionality works fine, but I've noticed when I try to send larger files (1MB+), it doesnt successfully write all the bytes before closing (Ex: tried sending 5mb, and it only sent 902 bytes). Is there a way to have the code wait for the stream to finish writing before closing the stream? Below is the code and the stack trace. Essentially the send message method is called when a file is attached and sent (in a class that handles the GUI). In this case, I wasnt trying to receive data from the client, just send data TO the client.

EDIT:I am aware that I only have the byte array set to 1MB right now. I had it at 5MB, and it was still only writing <1MB. Even at 1MB, it was still only writing 902 bytes.

EDIT2: I have posted some of the code on the CLIENT side that handles receiving the data.

```
public void sendMessage(File file) {
    if(mOut != null) {
        try {
            FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(file);               
            byte[] message = new byte[1024 * 1024];
            inStream.read(message);
            mOut.write(message, 0, message.length);
            mOut.flush();
            inStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}

public void run() { 
    super.run();
    running = true;
    try {
        System.out.println("S: Connecting...");
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
        Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
        linked = true;
        System.out.println("S: Receiving...");

        try {
            mOut =client.getOutputStream();
            InputStream in = client.getInputStream();
            while(running) {
                byte[] message = new byte[1024 * 1024];
                 in.read(message);
                if(message != null && messageListener != null) {
                    messageListener.messageReceived(message);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("S:Error");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            client.close();
            System.out.println("S:Done");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("S: Error");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at Server.sendMessage(Server.java:34)
at ServerBoard$2.actionPerformed(ServerBoard.java:57)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at Server.run(Server.java:58)
```

Here is a code snippet for the client.

```
    public void run() {
    mRun = true;
    serverMessage = new byte[1024 * 1024];
    try {
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);
        Log.e("TCP Client", "C:Connecting...");
        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
        try {
            in = socket.getInputStream();
            while(mRun) {
                 in.read(serverMessage);
                if(serverMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                    mMessageListener.messageReceived(new String(serverMessage));
            }
                serverMessage = null;
            }

            Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER","S:Received Message: '" + serverMessage + "'");

        } catch(Exception ex) {
            Log.e("TCP","S: Error", ex);
        } finally {
            socket.close();
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        Log.e("TCP","C: Error", ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't write files larger than 1MB when your byte buffer is only 1MB in size. You are filling up the buffer, writing it and closing the output stream. Perhaps try using a BufferedReader and a loop instead

Comment: Ah yes, I did change it to see what the max I could write was. I had it at 5MB, and it still wasnt writing the whole thing. Even with 1MB, it was only writing 902 bytes.

Comment: Is your while loop running more than once?

Comment: Always put a loop around "read" with sockets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, JavaDoc of [read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D%29):

> Reads some number of bytes from the input stream and stores them into
>   the buffer array b. The number of bytes actually read is returned as
>   an integer. This method blocks until input data is available, end of
>   file is detected, or an exception is thrown.

As the source is a socket, it may returns less bytes than expected, even if the buffer is sized at 1 MByte, returning 902 KBytes is Ok. You have to loop until end of stream.

The following method read all bytes, than calls listeners:

```
byte[] message = new byte[0]; 
byte[] buffer  = new byte[4096];
int    len;
while(( len = is.read( buffer )) > -1 ) {
   byte[] tmp = new byte[message.length+len];
   System.arraycopy( message, 0, tmp, 0, message.length );
   System.arraycopy( buffer , 0, tmp, message.length, len );
   message = tmp;
}
messageListener.messageReceived( message );
```

As you can see, a lot of reallocations occurs: you have to redesign your protocol to send the size of the file first and allocate once the receive buffer.

Comment: I am not trying to receive any data when I get the exception though, so I do not understand how reading and receiving bytes is the issue?

Comment: "reset by peer", the cause is in the other side. Post the code of the other side.

Comment: My answer is applicable to the client: a socket gives data as the network transport them, not all in one chunk. You have to loop around "read".

Comment: @kaptaincooke - when the InputStream is a Socket, read() will almost never return anything more than 65K; usually less thank 1600 bytes. This is because the OS will give you back as much as there is received and buffered at the time of the call, which usually isn't that much as you require - essentially, when there's nothing buffered the process will wait, but as soon as there's at least one byte you will get back what there is. Loop the loop get all the contents of the message; also, fix your protocol to pre-send the length of the message.

Comment: That seemed to work. I also changed the send message function to send the data in 1KB chunks. It receives these chunks just fine and pieces them together (however, for a 4MB file, the client crashed after a while. My guess is something to do with the memory?)

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the read buffer to null before finishing reading:

```
 in = socket.getInputStream();
 while(mRun) {
     in.read(serverMessage);
     if(serverMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
         mMessageListener.messageReceived(new String(serverMessage));
     }
     serverMessage = null;
}
```

this will cause a NullPointerException and your code will close the socket.

Answer (score 0):

Set `socket.setSendBufferSize(1024)` (which you are using to send) also make sure while receiving there you read in chunk of `1024` bytes.